# AngularJS: Apply a css class when a filter return no result

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-class

I've created a kind of glossary with AngularJS

When i click on an alphabet list buttons,  a function (categoryFilterFn), filter the json data by categories. I would like to apply a CSS to the button, when no results is returned by the filter.
 For example if i click on the Z button, no exist related entry in the json file, so the filter return nothing, and the Z letter button will be set with a white color with css. I don't know how to apply this using ng-clas. The code here:

```
<div ng-app="essaiApp">
  <section ng-controller="EssaiCtrl">
    <button type="button" ng-repeat="letter in alphabet" ng-click="selectCategory(letter)">
      {{letter}}
    </button>
    <div ng-repeat="item in todo.items | filter:categoryFilterFn">
      {{item.categoria}}
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

the controller:

```
essaiApp.controller("EssaiCtrl", function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.todo = model;
    var selectedCategory = null;

    $scope.selectCategory = function (newCategory) {
        selectedCategory = newCategory;
    }

    $scope.categoryFilterFn = function (polo) {
        return selectedCategory == null ||
            polo.categoria == selectedCategory;
    }

    $scope.alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
});
```

Comment: Can you post the content of `model`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the filtered result:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in filteredItems = ( todo.items | filter:categoryFilterFn)">
```

Move `selectedCategory` to `$scope`:

```
$scope.selectedCategory = null;

$scope.selectCategory = function(newCategory) {
  $scope.selectedCategory = newCategory;
}
```

Use `ng-class` on the buttons:

```
ng-class="{ 'no-result': selectedCategory === letter && !filteredItems.length }"
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Gl1i4dLyCCwuorQHB5SS?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it's working fine. I'm still a newbie with AngularJS, your code help me to understand better ng-class.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to tasseKatt's solution, you can manage your filtered array in the controller:

```
$scope.selectCategory = function(newCategory) {
  $scope.filtered = [];
  $scope.selectedCategory = newCategory;
}

$scope.categoryFilterFn = function(item) {
  if (item == $scope.selectedCategory)
    $scope.filtered.push(item);

  return item == $scope.selectedCategory
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/oOSOGPjaq9g7DaWRaFks?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your alternative,  I will study and apply your code with calm.  It helps me to understand better AngularJS.

Comment: +1 Good call, preferred when there already is a custom filter function defined in the controller